# React hook override same id array with object data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following data type:
[image]

I use this code to search same QID to write stuAnswer.
And this array length keeps in 20. Because QID just this range.
But get **TypeError: prevAnswers.QID is not iterable**

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {

        const id = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;

        setStuA(prevAnswers => [
            ...prevAnswers.QID,
            ...prevAnswers.answer,
            {
                stuAnswer: value,
                isCorrect: false
            }
        ]);

    };
```

and I want to check stuAnswer == answer

Then set it to *isCorrect* col.
Can I use condition expression in Hook? 
I saw doc say that can't use condition expression in Hook.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're trying to destructure a string ? if i'm not wrong it should be `[...prevAnswers, {stuAnswer: value, isCorrect: false } ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to iterate each "item".

The condition inside the `.map()` will check whether to return the modified item or not.

```
const handleChange = e => {
  const id = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;

  setStuA(items => (
    items.map(item => (
      item.QID === id ?
        { ...item, stuAnswer: value, isCorrect: item.answer === value }
        : item
    ))
  )
}
```

Comment: Your code is described as a very simple and clear way to implement this concept. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Creek glad to be of help. Continue to promote [clean code](https://www.amazon.sg/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882).